# SetWindowLong & SetLayeredWindowAttributes doesnt work on different user C#

Tags: api, windows-xp, opacity, alpha, setwindowlong

**The goal is**

I want to change the opacity of some application (target) running on win xp.

**The situation**

- I logged in win xp as AD (active dir) user account (some-domain\username)
- most of the target applications are run as local user or another ad user

**The problem and my Question**

`SetWindowLong` & `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` doesn't work on target application that run as other user account. But it works on target application that runs under the same user account (logged user account)

***How to change other app's window opacity that run as different user account?***

**Illustration app**

It's a win form app  (let's call it OpaciToggler.exe). I have 2 buttons (btnRunSomething and btnHideThatThing) and a textbox (txtPid). As simple as that.

When I click the btnRunSomething, it run an .exe as different user. All the details is in the app.config. In this case I run this application (OpaciToggler.exe, from the debug/bin) as different user (localComputer\user1)

The txtPid is for manual pid input. Usually I open the task manager (win > run > taskmgr) and find the pid (under the process tab) of any application (target) I want to test with, then type it here.

When I click the btnHideThatThing, it'll toggle the opacity of the target application (whose pid in the txtPid)

**Code C#**

This is how I call the target app.

```cs
    private void btnRunSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        p.StartInfo.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartInfoDomain"]; 
        p.StartInfo.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartInfoUserName"]; 

        p.StartInfo.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartInfoFileName"];
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartInfoArguments"];

        System.String rawPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartInfoPassword"];
        System.Security.SecureString encPassword = new System.Security.SecureString();

        foreach (System.Char c in rawPassword)
        {
            encPassword.AppendChar(c);
        }

        p.StartInfo.Password = encPassword;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        p.Start();
    }
```

This is how I try to call the opacity thing

```cs
    private void btnHideThatThing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // manual input pid 
        int pid = int.Parse(txtPid.Text);
        IntPtr mwh = Process.GetProcessById(pid).MainWindowHandle;
        doHideThing(mwh);  

        // doHideThing(Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(txtPid.Text)).MainWindowHandle);
    }
```

The hide method

```cs
    private void doHideThing(IntPtr hndl)
    {
        SetWindowLong(hndl, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hndl, GWL_EXSTYLE) ^ WS_EX_LAYERED).ToString();
        // _whatNow = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hndl, 0, (255 * 20) / 100, LWA_ALPHA).ToString();
        // _whatNow = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        RedrawWindow(hndl, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero,
            RedrawWindowFlags.Erase | RedrawWindowFlags.Invalidate |
            RedrawWindowFlags.Frame | RedrawWindowFlags.AllChildren);            
    }
```

other codes

```cs
    private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    private const int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
    private const int LWA_ALPHA = 0x2;
    private const int LWA_COLORKEY = 0x1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool RedrawWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lprcUpdate, IntPtr hrgnUpdate, RedrawWindowFlags flags);
```

RedrawWindowFlags enum (I don't remember where I get this)

```cs
[Flags()]
enum RedrawWindowFlags : uint
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Invalidates the rectangle or region that you specify in lprcUpdate or hrgnUpdate.
    /// You can set only one of these parameters to a non-NULL value. If both are NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE invalidates the entire window.
    /// </summary>
    Invalidate = 0x1,

    /// <summary>Causes the OS to post a WM_PAINT message to the window regardless of whether a portion of the window is invalid.</summary>
    InternalPaint = 0x2,

    /// <summary>
    /// Causes the window to receive a WM_ERASEBKGND message when the window is repainted.
    /// Specify this value in combination with the RDW_INVALIDATE value; otherwise, RDW_ERASE has no effect.
    /// </summary>
    Erase = 0x4,

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the rectangle or region that you specify in lprcUpdate or hrgnUpdate.
    /// You can set only one of these parameters to a non-NULL value. If both are NULL, RDW_VALIDATE validates the entire window.
    /// This value does not affect internal WM_PAINT messages.
    /// </summary>
    Validate = 0x8,

    NoInternalPaint = 0x10,

    /// <summary>Suppresses any pending WM_ERASEBKGND messages.</summary>
    NoErase = 0x20,

    /// <summary>Excludes child windows, if any, from the repainting operation.</summary>
    NoChildren = 0x40,

    /// <summary>Includes child windows, if any, in the repainting operation.</summary>
    AllChildren = 0x80,

    /// <summary>Causes the affected windows, which you specify by setting the RDW_ALLCHILDREN and RDW_NOCHILDREN values, to receive WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_PAINT messages before the RedrawWindow returns, if necessary.</summary>
    UpdateNow = 0x100,

    /// <summary>
    /// Causes the affected windows, which you specify by setting the RDW_ALLCHILDREN and RDW_NOCHILDREN values, to receive WM_ERASEBKGND messages before RedrawWindow returns, if necessary.
    /// The affected windows receive WM_PAINT messages at the ordinary time.
    /// </summary>
    EraseNow = 0x200,

    Frame = 0x400,

    NoFrame = 0x800
}
```

**Example, Test and Test Result**

- logged in win xp as domainA\ad_user1
- run the OpaciToggler.exe application (Instance1, run as domainA\ad_user1)
- Then I click the run something. It opens another OpaciToggler.exe (Instance2), runs as another user account (run as localcomputer\l_user1) OR right click the .exe then click run as..

Instance1

- pid: 1234
- run as: domainA\ad_user1
- txtPid: 5678  (Instance2, doesn't work)
- txtPid: 1234  (self, works)
- txtPid: any pid run as the same account (ex: notepad.exe, calc.exe, etc, works)

Instance2

- pid: 5678
- run as: localcomputer\l_user1
- txtPid: 1234  (Instance 1, doesnt work)
- txtPid: 5678  (self, works)
- txtPid: any pid run as the same account (localcomputer\l_user1) (ex: notepad.exe, calc.exe, etc, doesn't work!!)

**Again, my Question**

***How to change other app's window opacity that run as different user account?***

Thanks and sorry for my bad English :(.